# How to block typing in Entry while still keeping its functionality?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I'm making a calculator using Tkinter. I want to be able to block the user from typing directly in the Entry, but still, i don't want to simply deactivate the Entry entirely, because i need my input commands from the buttons for it to work.

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.title("Calculadora")
root.resizable(height = False, width = False)

#functions------------------------------------------------------------------

display_input = StringVar()

number_storage = ""

def button_click(buttons):
    global number_storage
    number_storage = number_storage + str(buttons)
    display_input.set(number_storage)


#row 1---------------------------------------------------------------------------

display = Entry(root, textvariable = display_input, justify = 'right', font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 18), bg = "black", fg = "white", bd = 25).grid(columnspan = 4)

Button7 = Button(root, command = lambda: button_click(7), bd = 10, text= "7", padx = 9, font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 15), bg = "black", fg = "white").grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = 'ew')

Button8 = Button(root, command = lambda: button_click(8), bd = 10, text = "8", padx = 9, font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 15), bg = "black", fg = "white").grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = 'ew')

Button9 =  Button(root, command = lambda: button_click(9), bd = 10, text = "9", padx = 9, font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 15), bg = "black", fg = "white").grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = 'ew')

Division = Button(root, command = lambda: button_click("/"), bd = 10, text = "/", padx = 9, font = ("Simplified Arabian Fixed", 15), bg = "grey30", fg = "white").grid(column = 3, row = 1, sticky = 'ew')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Why not use `Label` instead of `Entry`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `state="readonly"` when constructing the `Entry`; it still allows selecting the text, and changing `display_input` programmatically still changes the display, but it doesn't allow direct user input.

Per [the docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#Tkinter.Entry.config-method):

> *state=*
>
> > The entry state: **NORMAL**, **DISABLED**, or “readonly” (same as **DISABLED**, but contents can still be selected and copied). Default is **NORMAL**. Note that if you set this to **DISABLED** or “readonly”, calls to `insert` and `delete` are ignored. (state/State)